# How to delay a php execution with "at" and keep sudo rights

Tags: php, sudo, delay, at-job

I didn't find what I'm searching for, so, here I am.

I try to delay a script.php execution to "now + 1 minutes" with the "at" unix command, keeping the sudo rights

My problem is that this script.php, executed by "at", doesn't have the rights to create/edit/delete files or directores, or to run a script.sh i created.

I try many differents ways and came to that:

```
<?php
exex("echo password | sudo -u username -S echo 'echo password | sudo -u username -S php ".dirname(__FILE__).'/script.php '.$this->getQueueParams()."' | at now + 1 minutes");
```

This command is runing well when i copy/past it in my terminal, but not from PHP:

- Sometimes it works but exception are triggered for rights reasons
- Sometimes it simply doesn't execute the "at" command, en exec() return a code "1"

I also edited suoders to add the rights for apache's user (www-data) to execute all the commands i need (echo, chmod, chown, script.sh, ...), still don't works.

Many thanks for your help!

Jessy

Comment: sudo is not preserved by at/cron, because you'll be running under the uid of the user the job was scheduled under. if you want root rights on a script, either do it as an suid binary (bad bad bad idea), or as a script under the root user. sudo still requires a password, unless you allow password-less sudo (also a bad bad bad idea).

Comment: Hello and many thanks for your answer!
This is a local server only accessible via local ways, security is not a real priority.

The problem is the "password" and "username" i specified in the command line above are my access (and i'm root user). And it still don't want to work

Any idea?

Thanks again!